# Function to run the program on windows loading c++

Tags: c++, windows

I was wondering how to make a program that will load everytime the users logs in their windows session. So when they enter windows the program is up and running. If possible without admin rights needed.

So what i need is a function inside my code that will make a copy of the .exe file to the start-up menu and check if there isnt the file already

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming problem. You can write any app you want and add it to the startup folder. (http://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/)

Comment: But isnt there a way to copy the file from his current dir to the start-up folder inside the program ?

Comment: @NotanNimda Of course there's a way to copy files from one location to another; even executables. Can you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve, because this is far too vague.